# Determine cell location in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Given a specific row number and column index how can I calculate the cell location (IE: Location.Point) inside a DataGridView?

The reason I need the location of the cell is so I can position a button inside the cell to allow for folder browsing (the datagridview shows folderpaths).

Alternative suggestions about how to accomplish this welcome.

Comment: Your idea here is quite fragile. There are better ways to add buttons to cells in a `DataGridView`. The cells can contain any type of control that you like, including custom controls. I recommend checking into this first.

Comment: Why don't you use DataGridViewButtonColumn? It is part of .NET Framework.

Comment: Because what I want to achieve is a textbox with a button beside it (I'm sure there is a better way but can't quite work it out - prob inheriting DataGridViewColumn).

Comment: I would use two columns... I don't understand why they have to be in the same cell.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can't really find a point for a DGV cell because cells occupy a rectangular area in a DGV.  However, you can find this area by using the [DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getcelldisplayrectangle.aspx). It returns a `Rectangle` for the display area of a DGV Cell given by the Cell's column and row indices.  If you really want a point you can easily use the `Rectangle` to construct Points for any of the `Rectangle`'s four corners.

```
// Get Rectangle for second column in second row.
var cellRectangle = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, 1, true);
// Can create Points using the Rectangle if you want.
Console.WriteLine("Top Left     x:{0}\t y:{1}", cellRectangle.Left, cellRectangle.Top);
Console.WriteLine("Bottom Right x:{0}\t y:{1}", cellRectangle.Right, cellRectangle.Bottom);
```

But I agree with your question's commenters; it would be better to create a custom DataGridViewColumn and host your TextBox and Button there.  [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) of doing this for the DateTimePicker control:

Comment: I ended up using your suggestion on the correct way to create a column. It worked well. Thank you!

Comment: This MSDN you provided is exactly what I'm looking for.