# Open a popup from just below of current selected cell of datagrid view

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a datagridview with some data. I have added a custom button which will show when i click on a cell. By clicking this button a popup form will be opened. My requirement is only set the location of popup form that is should show just below the selected cell of the datagridview. below is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: do you have some already popup control? If so, you should show some methods or properties it has.

Comment: You should be able to calculate the location of the cell (don't forget to include the rest of the form in that location), then set the child form's constructor to take a `Point` as an argument and set its location using that, I think. [This might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937140/determine-cell-location-in-datagridview)

Comment: Just adding a comment to let you know I heavily editted my answer and it's pretty close to what you want, now.

Comment: @KingKing yes i have popup control. actually it is just a winform which contains datagrid view control on it nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work 100% but it's a starting point, based off my comment:

Main Form:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Point _cellClick;
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var h = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height;

        if (MousePosition.Y % h == 0)
        {
            _cellClick = new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);
        }
        else
        {
            var y = MousePosition.Y;

            do
            {
                y++;
            } while (y % h != 0);

            _cellClick = new Point(MousePosition.X, y);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f = new Form2(_cellClick);
        f.ShowDialog(this);
    }
```

Child Form:

```
    private Point loc;
    public Form2(Point location)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loc = location;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetDesktopLocation(loc.X, loc.Y);
    }
```

**Edit** This is really close to what you're looking for, the only issue is that the child form doesn't show up "adjacent" to the cell, but exactly where the mouse was when they clicked on the cell.

You could probably do some basic arithmetic to figure out the height of a cell to offset MousePosition.Y so that the child form shows up adjacent to it. I *think* you just need to round the coordinate to the nearest multiple of N, where N is `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height`, rounding up.

**Edit 2** I just edited the code to try something like this, and now the child form tends to show up just a little bit below the row.

Comment: HI @sab669 Thanks alot for your help. i used this code exactly you defined above and am getting my desire output. Appreciated your help.

Comment: this code is not really good. When the first row `Height` is large enough, (say about 100 or even 200) and your form location `Top` is at a certain point, the Location of the popup may be much far from the actual clicking point.

Comment: @KingKing Yea, I only did some basic testing on a very small app but it works pretty closely and it's a starting point for improvement. If you have a better solution I'd like to see it. I suppose a better way would be to somehow translate the coords of the cell to the screen position and then launch the form there, rather than how I did it... But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @sab669 the code can be much simpler and more accurate by using the method `DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(...)` and using the method `PointToScreen` to convert to screen coordinates. You can locate the popup at the exact **bottom line** of the clicked cell.

Comment: @KingKing Ah, I had tried messing around with the Rectangle and using the Bottom Left to get the position but I was unaware of `PointToScreen` to translate it, so the results were pretty poor.

Comment: @sab669 i am facing a problem. if my selected cell's located in bottom of the screen so my popup form is not fit in the screen means i am not able to see complete form. it's got cropped. my requirement is if space is available it should display below of selected cell other wise above of the selected cell.

Comment: This works well. The key is the SetDesktopLocation must be called in Form_Load.